# casting de ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro

Galera , Não  consigo  entender o porquê de fazer o casting entre ponteiros isso tem algum impacto no código ou e só para deixar o código legível como por exemplo essa linha de uma função:

```
 void* getPhysicalAddress (pdirectory* dir, uint32_t virt) {

   ... 
   ... 

   return (void*) ((uint32_t*) (pagedir[virt >> 22] & ~0xfff))[virt << 10 >> 10 >> 12];


}
```

O porque fazer `(void*)((uint32_t*)(..)`  por exemplo? 
Gostaria de saber quando usar o **cast** de **ponteiros**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve entender que os tipos (`int`, `char`, `long`, etc.) tem um tamanho definido pela plataforma, alguns mantém seu tamanho em todas as plataformas, como no caso do tipo `char` de `8 bits`.

Os ponteiros apontam para endereço de memória, porém, você necessita dizer pra que tipo (tamanho) de região de memória você quer apontar, para que o compilador saiba como lidar com as informações que o ponteiro aponta (alocações, cálculos, etc).

O tipo `void` é uma exceção das regras de tipos. O tipo `void` tem tamanho de `1 byte`, porém, ele não armazena nenhum dado. O ponteiro de tipo `void` só pode apontar pra outro ponteiro de mesmo tipo (essa regra serve para os todos os tipos), geralmente ele é usado para "generalizar" dados. É muito usado para quando você não sabe que tipo de dado irá receber, porém, ao recebe-lo é necessário fazer um `cast` para o tipo da variável que está recebendo esse dado, para que seja possível manipulá-lo (alocações, cálculos, atribuições, etc.).

O `cast` serve para forçar uma variável a ser um tipo diferente do que ela foi declara. Ele é usado para otimizar as operações e até mesmo tornar possível fazer operação entre duas ou mais variáveis sem que o resultado seja algo inesperado.

Referente a sua linha de código, vou dividi-la em quatro para fazer uma análise:

Primeira parte:

Nesse trecho é feita uma operação de de deslocamento do valor da variável `virt`, para pegar os 10 bits mais significativos do dado contido na variável e o valor resultante servirá de índice para o array `pagedir`. Do valor contido em `pagedir` de índice `[virt >> 22]` é feita mais duas operações, uma de negação (~) e uma AND (&) e resultará em um outro valor, que me parece ser um outro endereço:

```
pagedir[virt >> 22] & ~0xfff
```

Segunda parte:

O resultado da primeira parte, ao que me parece, retorna um endereço, então, nessa segunda parte está sendo indexado (apontada) outra região de memória a partir desse endereço:

```
(pagedir[virt >> 22] & ~0xfff))[virt << 10 >> 10 >> 12];
```

Os parênteses, em volta de `pagedir` e nas operações feitas com ela, querem dizer que o endereço resultante dessas operações será indexado pelos colchetes e dentro dos colchetes é feita uma indexação que equivale a uma aritmética de ponteiros: `(...)[virt << 10 >> 10 >> 12]`

Terceira parte:

Nessa momento o cast de `(uint32_t*)` está dizendo que a região de memória indexada (apontada), conforme dito na segunda parte, deverá ser tratada na base (tamanho) de `uint32`_t, então, qualquer operação (alocações, cálculos, atribuições, etc.) realizada será nessa base:

```
((uint32_t*) (pagedir[virt >> 22] & ~0xfff))[virt << 10 >> 10 >> 12];
```

Quarta parte:

Por fim, toda a operação é apontada por um tipo `void`, pois a função retorna um dado deste tipo e, ao meu ver, essa função está deixando para quem receber seu retorno definir como ele quer armazenar o valor retornado, dessa forma quem receber esse retorno terá que fazer um `cast` para algum tipo:

```
return (void*) ((uint32_t*) (pagedir[virt >> 22] & ~0xfff))[virt << 10 >> 10 >> 12];
```

Vou deixar um link para que vocÊ encontre mais informações sobre ponteiros: [Programar em C/Ponteiros](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Ponteiros)

Comment: Excelente resposta Roger.

Comment: roger então no caso quando faço isso (uint32_t*) (pagedir[virt >> 22] & ~0xfff)  estao pegando a page vir e transformando para uint32_t e 0xfff para  uint32_t também?

Comment: user46542 eu editei minha resposta para ficar mais completa. Percebi que haviam partes importantes que esqueci de comentar. Peço desculpas por ter esquecido. Espero não ter causado maiores danos ao seu entendimento. Peço que leia novamente a resposta e verifique se ficou alguma dúvida.

Comment: Nossa cara valeu mesmo !!!

Comment: roger me surgiu mais uma duvida se colocar (unsigned char *)  a expresão vai ser tratada como 1 byte ?

Comment: O que vai acontecer é que os endereços indexados pela expressão  `(...)[virt << 10 >> 10 >> 12]"` (como eu havia explicado na segunda parte) apontarão pra blocos de memórias de 1 byte. 

Um array nada mais é que um ponteiro, então, um ponteiro `uint32_t *var;` é equivalente a um array `uint32_t var[ ]`. Se você trocar o cast `uint32_t*` por `unsigned char*` o ponteiro passará a apontar blocos de memórias de 8 bits (1 byte).

Comment: Imagine que um ponteiro `uint32_t ptrVar[ ];` esteja apontado pra alguma região de memória. Por `uint32_t` ser um tipo de 32 bits, logo, `ptrVar[ ];`  aponta pra um bloco de memória de 32 bits -> **01101001 00101010 00100011 00111011**. Quando você fizer um cast  de `(unsigned char *) ptrVar[ ];` , `ptrVar[ ];` passara a apontar para um bloco de memória de 8 bits (1 byte), então, se apontá-lo para mesma posição de memória anterior ele apontará para apenas 8 bits (ver se a plataforma é big endian ou litle andian) -> **00111011** (considerando que a plataforma é litle andian).

Comment: Agora entendi tudo vlw

Answer (score 0):

O casting de um ponteiro para (void*) é necessário para algumas funções que utilizam um "ponteiro genérico" como argumento. Um ponteiro, além de apontar um endereço de uma variável, também guarda o tamanho em memória que aquela variável ocupa. Quando fazemos o casting, estamos alterando o tamanho da variável que o ponteiro armazena.

Comment: Ponteiros não guardam o tamanho do endereço que apontam. Eles têm um tipo e cada tipo tem um tamanho.